# why has my fox rear shocks adjusting lever popped out?

Tags: full-suspension

as i put in my title my fox rear shocks mode adjuster and rebound adjuster has popped out and exposed a little metal ball, I can no more adjust my rear shock but don't know why this has happened. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: You should include some pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that your adjustor knob looks like this: 
[image]

If you look closelly to that image, over the "2" you'll see a triangle. Over the triangle you'll see a tiny hole. In that hole there is an alen bolt, (maybe 1mm or 1.5mm) which retains the knob in its place. That bolt must have been lose so the knob fell. The metal ball is just there to provide the click sound and feel for the compression or rebound adjustor.

So, fully undo the bolt, place the knob in it's place, tighten the bolt (not very much), and you are good to go. Test by rotating both directions and expect to hear and feel the clicks. Make sure you return the settings to their original position. If unsure, consult with someone who knows, your LBS, or ask here.

This exact mechanism exists in almost all compression and rebound knobs in common suspensions. e.g [image] and [image]